# ¿Como puedo comprobar si el usuario logueado es admin por su id?

Tags: asp.net

Estoy trabajando en mi primer Login en este lenguaje, la cual al ingresar las credenciales correctas (usario y contraseña) te dirigirá a una pagina especifica dependiendo si eres un user comun o administrador segun el idRole asignado, tal y como se muestra.

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sqlDa.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Session["username"] = txtUserName.Text.Trim();
        if (dt.Rows[0]["IdRole"].ToString() == "2")
            Response.Redirect("user/Default.aspx");
        else if
            (dt.Rows[0]["IdRole"].ToString() == "1")
            Response.Redirect("admin/Default.aspx");

    }
    else
    {
     lblErrorMessage.Visible = true; 
    }
```

En las paginas al que te direcciona tiene una condición que evita que no puedas ingresar a ellas almenos que haya una session actual.

El problema es que si un usuario comun logeado simplemente cambia la direccion de esto; **user/Default.aspx** a esto; 
**admin/Default.aspx** este ya tiene acceso a sus controles. ¿Que metodos puedo utilizar para resolver estos problemas?

Comment: Te sugiero que al igual que guardas en una variable de sesión el nombre del usuario validado, añadas otra variable de sesión en la que guardes el rol que tiene el usuario validado. Posteriormente, cuando accedas a las páginas que requieren validación, compruebes el rol al cual pertenece el usuario que accede, para decidir si puede o no acceder a esa página en concreto

Comment: el sqlDa es un objeto creado? y que proc. almacenado mandas llamar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para evitar que cuando cambien la URL en los controladores puedes user al atributo

```
[Authorize(Role="admin")]  todos los admin
[Authorize]  todos los user logueados
```

si usas Asp.Net Identity puede revisar el rol User.IsInRole("RoleName")